# Concat rows based on condition

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with a table that has values like this

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Size | 1 |
| 123 | Size | 2 |
| 123 | Size | 3 |
| 123 | Type | Shoes |
| 234 | Size | 6 |
| 234 | Size | 7 |
| 234 | Type | Shirt |

I want to CONCAT the answers if the name = size. So, I'd love to do this:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Size | 1, 2, 3 |
| 123 | Type | Shoes |
| 234 | Size | 6, 7 |
| 234 | Type | Shirt |

My thought was to use a case when size = 'name' then concat? But I'm not sure if this is the correct use. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-aggregate.html):

```sql
SELECT id, name, string_agg(value, ',')
  FROM a
 GROUP BY id, name
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

Output:

| ID | Name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Size | 1,2,3 |
| 123 | Type | Shoes |
| 234 | Size | 6,7 |
| 234 | Type | Shirt |

Here is a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxfsbgcwTmVm9AoWnNuYTW/1) showing how it works. This is assuming that there is only one column with name = Type, if there are more this will merge those too.